# Externally loaded MovieClip won't Stop()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have externally loaded a .swf asset that is an animated character with a timeline. I load the clip as follows:

```
m_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoaderComplete);
m_loader.load(new URLRequest("test.swf"));

private function LoaderComplete(e:Event):void 
{
var movie:MovieClip = m_loader.content as MovieClip;
stage.addChild(movie);
movie.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

But the animation just keeps on playing. Stop() also does not work. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, I feel like it has to do with being an externally loaded .swf file.

Comment: How the test.swf's timeline looks like? Also try not to separate loaded content with it's loader - it will make problems with unloading it. - Does your test.swf on it's main timeline contains all animation or you have it in movieclips that are placed on main timeline?

Answer (score 1):

If you have library objects that are on the stage but have their own timeline, you'll need to make sure that all of them are stopped.  What happens when you publish the movie.swf - does it keep running?

Comment: Yeah, if I run the movie in CS6 it is constantly running. What do you mean by all of them are stopped? Could you give a specific example or a code snippet? Thanks :)

Comment: If you can't control the swf as a standalone you can't control it as a loaded swf.  You'll need to put a stop(); on the first frame.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to look at the movieclips on the stage and see which are running and put a stop(); in the first frame of their timelines.